# Calculating the Number of Conjugacy Classes and Size for Non-Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Suppose I have a non-abelian group $G$ of size 35. I want to calculate the number of conjugacy classes and their sizes. Because 35 is the product of two primes 5 and 7, I arrived at the conclusion that the $Z(G)$ is trivial. I know that I need to use the class equation here but how can I get this information from it? I feel like I can use Cauchy's theorem here too. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such group.

Comment: there is only one group of order $35$ up to isomorphism which is cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Use the uniqueness of Sylow 5-subgroup and Sylow 7-subgroup and the Sylow subgroups here are norm subgroups.So the 35 order group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups,hence it is commutative and cyclic.